# Linux script to create new directory with name as datestamp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, syntax

The current script is functional, but the output is slightly off. This is what I have so far.

```
echo "Which client are we backing up today? Choose one below."
ls -la /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/Clients | awk '{print $9}'

read varname

cd /usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/Clients/$varname

while true; do
    read -p "Backup files located in nagtech/backup to current client directory? (y/n) "  yn
    case $yn in
            [Yy]* ) cp -r /home/nagtech/backup $varname > mkdir$(date +m%-%d-%y); break;; 
            [Nn]* ) exit;;
    * ) echo "Please anwser yes or no.";;
    esac
done
```

My intention is to have a new DIRECTORY created and NAMED with the current date stamp if input is y. However its not quite there. Below is sample output when "y" is entered and $varname is set to "HELP".

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 16 root root 4096 Aug 22 18:36 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug 22 18:38 08.22.18
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Aug 24 17:45 mkdirm%d-18
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Aug 24 17:45 HELP
```

Comment: [Why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The destination of `cp` is the second argument to the command. You're using the date as the name of a file to redirect the output, but `cp` doesn't produce any output.

You need to execute the `mkdir` command to create the directory, and then use that as the destination of the `cp` command.

```
[Yy]* ) newdir=$(date +m%-%d-%y)
        mkdir "$newdir"
        cp -r /home/nagtech/backup "$newdir"
        ;;
```